# jquery menu with scrolling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I want to build a vertical menu bar like

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

But on the mouse over I need to show more that 15 up to 20 items. So I am thinking of it would be good if I show 5 items initially and provide a arrow at the bottom of the items, so on the user click I can show the next five items. Is there a menu plugin for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think people will find that annoying... why not make it wider and have columns in the pop-out column like [ebuyer](http://www.ebuyer.com/) has?

Comment: That is a good idea, but i have to show all items  on mouse over and I don't have anything like categories with some sub categories  to have them shown in that manner.

Comment: @NetDev I'm not sure that you need categories, you can just show them in columns with some kind of divider perhaps a 1px dotted line with a good bit of padding

Comment: is there a plugin to implement ebuyer menu.

Comment: not that I know of, I doubt it'll be that hard though. You'll just need to change the suckerfish CSS a little to make the sub menu wider and have the options display in columns within it.

Answer (score 1):

Such scrolling menus are among the most horrible piece of UI ever invented. Please do your users a favor: Avoid it at all costs.

Why not have multi-columns menus instead? Or organize the choices in submenus. Although this is fairly horrible as well.

I second Ian Barker's solution: I find the ebuyer solution very elegant.